# How do I make night cycle like Dino Chrome?

Tags: unity

I want to add a day/night system cycling to my runner game like the game Dino Chrome. The condition is when the score reaches `100` it will be `night` then when it reaches `100` again will be `day`.

I tried with this code but nothing changed in my game:

```cs
if (_GameManager.instance.score % 100 == 0)
{
     fadeToBlack = !fadeFromBlack;

     if (fadeToBlack)
     {
          cam.backgroundColor = new Color(Mathf.MoveTowards(cam.backgroundColor.r, 1f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime), 
                                          Mathf.MoveTowards(cam.backgroundColor.g, 1f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime), 
                                          Mathf.MoveTowards(cam.backgroundColor.b, 1f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime), 
                                          cam.backgroundColor.a);
     }

     if (fadeFromBlack)
     {
          cam.backgroundColor = new Color(Mathf.MoveTowards(cam.backgroundColor.r, 255f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime),
                                          Mathf.MoveTowards(cam.backgroundColor.g, 255f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime),
                                          Mathf.MoveTowards(cam.backgroundColor.b, 255f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime), 
                                          cam.backgroundColor.a);
     }
}
```

Eventually I want to change all game object colors via script with smooth, but for now I just want to apply a change to the camera background.

and this is my whole script

````cs
    public static _ObstacleManager instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public float maxTime;
    float timer;

    [Header("CommongObstacle")]
    public GameObject[] Obstacles;

    [Header("BirdObstacle")]
    public GameObject[] buwungObstacle;

    [Header("MeteorObstacle")]
    public GameObject Meteor;
    public Transform[] spawnpoint;

    int choosedSpawnMeteor;
    int choosedObstacle;

    [Header("NightCycle")]
    public float fadeSpeed = 2f;
    public bool fadeToBlack, fadeFromBlack;
    public Camera cam;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (_GameManager.instance.isStarted)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer >= maxTime)
            {
                GenerateObstacle();

                if (_GameManager.instance.score >= 400)
                {
                    GenerateBuwungObstacle();
                }

                timer = 0;
            }

            if (_GameManager.instance.score % 100 == 0 && activeFade == null)
            {
                fadeToBlack = !fadeToBlack;

                Color color = fadeToBlack ? Color.black : Color.white;

                activeFade = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(color));
            }
        }
    }

    //kelipatan 200 
    public void GeneratedMeteorObs()
    {
        choosedSpawnMeteor = Random.Range(0, spawnpoint.Length);
        GameObject meteorGo = Instantiate(Meteor, spawnpoint[choosedSpawnMeteor].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public void GenerateObstacle()
    {
        choosedObstacle = Random.Range(0, Obstacles.Length);
        GameObject obstacle = Instantiate(Obstacles[choosedObstacle]);
    }

    public void GenerateBuwungObstacle()
    {
        choosedObstacle = Random.Range(0, buwungObstacle.Length);
        GameObject obstacle = Instantiate(buwungObstacle[choosedObstacle]);
    }

    // Store the fade in progress (so we don't accidentally double-start it)
    Coroutine activeFade;

    // Perform a fade over time, then clear the activeFade variable when done.
    IEnumerator FadeTo(Color destination)
    {
        Color start = cam.backgroundColor;

        for (float t = 0; t < 1f; t += Time.deltaTime / fadeSpeed)
        {
            cam.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(start, destination, t);
            yield return null;
        }

        cam.backgroundColor = destination;
        activeFade = null;
    }

```
````

Comment: You can not assume that everyone on this site is familiar with every game in existence. Instead of writing "Just like in this game" it would help if you posted some screenshots and explained what you want to do in your own words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in this code.

You've taken the code that *performs* the colour transition, and nested it inside the conditional block that *triggers* the colour transition.

That means each time you hit a multiple of 100, you update the background colour for one single frame, then leave it constant until the next multiple of 100. Then you update the background colour in the opposite direction for one single frame.

You might be under the mistaken impression that `Mathf.MoveTowards()` kicks off a tween that runs independently in the background. It can't do that, because it doesn't take and hold a reference to the variable you'd want the tween to update next frame. It's just a math function that takes some numbers and returns a number - assigning its output to your desired variable each frame is your job.

You can also make this code much simpler by using `Color.Lerp`. Here's a corrected version:

```
// Store the fade in progress (so we don't accidentally double-start it)
Coroutine activeFade;

// Perform a fade over time, then clear the activeFade variable when done.
IEnumerator FadeTo(Color destination) {
    Color start = cam.backgroundColor;

    for (float t = 0; t < 1f; t += Time.deltaTime / fadeDuration) {
        cam.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(start, destination, t);
        yield return null;
    }

    cam.backgroundColor = destination;
    activeFade = null;
}

// Check for the trigger to start a new fade, and start it.
void Update() {
    if ((_GameManager.instance.score % 100) == 0 && activeFade == null) {
        fadeToBlack = !fadeToBlack;

        Color color = fadeToBlack ? Color.Black : Color.White;

        activeFade = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(color));
    }
}
```

Comment: This should fit the questions requirements but might cause some unexpected behavior if you just plug it in. The only major "bug" I can see is that the game may be constantly switching between day and night after the first 100 points if the score is not reset (which is weird for most games) so you may want another variable. It might also be better to use MoveTowards instead of Lerp and simply cancel the old transition Coroutine if a new one is needed. Also what happens if a player gets 200 points from a boss fight (transition to night or don't because this would cause 2 transitions)?

Comment: Thank you i believe this suppose to be work but, in my game the `camera` ignore to change background color do you know what happen ?.

Comment: @YouCanCallMeSyarif please read the answer. Your code is wrong, it's not supposed to work. You only change the background ONE TIME when the score reaches 100, and that one-time change is multiplied by deltaTime, so the change would be so minimal that you won't see it. You need to put the fade code outside of the "if score % 100 = 0", and only take into account whether it's day or night, that way the transition will continue after the score has changed.

Comment: I assumed this would be in a game where the score is continually increasing over time, so it would not still be a multiple of 100 when the fade finishes. I added the null check as a hedge against the score holding steady for just a few frames in a row. But you could easily store a `lastFadeStartedAt = _GameManager.instance.score` and then check `_GameManager.instance.score > lastFadeStartedAt` to decide when to start a new fade, rather than checking whether `activeFade == null`.